# Laravel 6.2 Requests - Returns Null on specific route

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Running on **Laravel 6.2 - Stable release**

I'm not entirely sure where i'm going wrong here - It works in one method but doesn't work in another. The only difference is the URL format.

(Simply trying to get the body information from a post request)

For instance I have this following method in a controller.

```
/** METHOD IS POST - URL FORMAT: SERVER.COM/$number **/
private function populate(Request $request, $number){
 //
 $request->get('x'); // Works
}
```

However when doing this:

```
  /* POST METHOD - URL FORMAT: server.com/$number/example/$position
private function unpopulate(Request $request, $number, $position){
     $request->get('x'); // Fails
}
```

**Populate Postman `DD`**

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#54
  #json: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#46
    #parameters: array:1 [
      "x" => "2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00"
    ]
  }
```

**Unpopulate Postman `DD`**

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#54
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#34
```

If I json_decode the `$request` in **unpopulate** then it returns:

```
  -_jsonRequest: {#287
    +"finished_at": "2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00"
```

But when trying to access it, I then get a null value.

```
$test = json_decode ( $request->getContent() ); // Decodes 
$test->x // Fails
isset($test->x) // Fails
```

Any ideas on how to fix this and why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a slightly different method for `get()` on the incoming form data than Symfony.

When data is coming in from a form, use `$request->input('x');` to avoid conflict.

This will help - but your issue may be linked to the incoming data.  If you `dd($request->all())` in your unpop method, and get null, the issue is something you haven't shown in your question on the form push.